# Counting the no. of nodes touched during deletion in a bst

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to calculate the no. of nodes touched while deleting a particular node in a binary search tree. I am unable to figure out where to put the statement count++; to fix the code.

```
public int delete(K key) {
        count=0;
        if(this.contains(key)){
            int pos=(int)djb2(key.toString(),BHTable.length);        
            BTNode root = BHTable[pos];
            BHTable[pos] = deleteRec(root, key);
            if(count2!=0)System.out.println(count2);
            else System.out.println(count);
        }
        else System.out.println("E");
        return -1;
    } 
    T odel;
    public BTNode deleteRec(BTNode root, K key) {

        if (root == null)  return root; 
        if (((Comparable)key).compareTo(root.key)<0) 
           {count++; root.left = deleteRec(root.left, key);}
        else if (((Comparable)key).compareTo(root.key) >0) 
           {count++; root.right = deleteRec(root.right, key);}
        else if(((Comparable)key).compareTo(root.key)==0&&! root.key.toString().equals(key.toString())))
           {count++; root.right = deleteRec(root.right, key);}
        else if(root.key.toString().equals(key.toString())){ 
            if (root.left == null) 
            { count++; return root.right;}
            else if (root.right == null) 
            { count++;  return root.left;}
            root.key = minValue(root.right); 
            root.obj = odel;
            root.right = deleteRec(root.right,(K)root.key); 
        } 
        return root; 
    } 
    K minValue(BTNode root)  { 
        K minv =(K) root.key; 
        while (root.left != null) { 
            minv =(K) root.left.key; 
            root = root.left; 
            count++;
        } 
        odel=(T)root.obj;
        return minv; 
    }
```

The displayed output is many times differing with the expected output by +-1.

Comment: My keys are the names(first+last) of students I inserted in the tree, and in case of same first names, I inserted the new one in the right subtree.

Comment: Why not pass count as a function argument? That way it'll be modified as the recursion proceeds. Also, you could attach the count to the key, and take it out right after you call the function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Where to increment it? @the_ritz

Comment: You'll need to provide more info on what K is. My solution assumes it's a string. If it's an object, add a count instance variable to K, and modify that before returning.

Comment: K is a <String, String> Pair. compareTo() method of Pair class compares two Pairs based on their first string and in case of the equal first string and unequal second string the entry is inserted in the right subtree.

Comment: And I don't have any syntax related issue or Java-specific issue; I want to what are the cases where I have to increment my count variable.

Comment: Well you need to provide an example of a tree and the counting method. You could just increment the counter every time it moves onto a new node. If your code isn't working, you might want to look at your logic first. If count is static, then my solution wouldn't be needed. Then again, you didn't include that bit in the code snippet. Also, check if you're counting the last node before returning.